WiFi network card not detected (either AX210 or MT7922)
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with Linux 6.8.0-40-generic on a HP Pavilion Laptop 15.
The issue I facing is that the WiFi card is not detected. I tried both an Mediatek MT7922 and an Intel AX210.
Note: I only upgraded the card, not the antennas. The previous card Realtek 8852BE was WiFi 6; these cards are WiFi 6e. I don't care about the 6 GHz band now, I am just mentioning if it makes any difference.
Now back to the issue:
Neither the AX210 or MT7922 cards are detected.

lspci for AX210

00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barcelo (rev c1)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 01)
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller

The only line I see added here for both cards versus running with no WiFi card plugged in is the following one:
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge  

Running lsusb for AX210 returns:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 30c9:0065 Luxvisions Innotech Limited HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 

OR for MT7922:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 30c9:0065 Luxvisions Innotech Limited HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e0f1 Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  


lspci -nnk for the AX210 returns:

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex [1022:1630]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex [103c:8a0e]
00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU [1022:1631]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU [103c:8a0e]
00:01.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
00:02.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1634]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1453]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1634]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1453]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus [1022:1635]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus [1022:1635]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 51)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b]
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e]
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0 [1022:166a]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1 [1022:166b]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2 [1022:166c]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3 [1022:166d]
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4 [1022:166e]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5 [1022:166f]
00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6 [1022:1670]
00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7 [1022:1671]
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 [144d:a808]
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd SSD 970 EVO/PRO [144d:a801]
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barcelo [1002:15e7] (rev c1)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Barcelo [103c:8a0e]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller [1002:1637]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller [103c:8a0e]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
03:00.2 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor [1022:15df]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor [103c:8a0e]
    Kernel driver in use: ccp
    Kernel modules: ccp
03:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1 [1022:1639]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1 [103c:8a0e]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
03:00.4 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1 [1022:1639]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1 [103c:8a0e]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
03:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor [1022:15e2] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor [103c:8a0e]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x, snd_pci_acp5x, snd_pci_acp6x, snd_acp_pci, snd_rpl_pci_acp6x, snd_pci_ps, snd_sof_amd_renoir, snd_sof_amd_rembrandt, snd_sof_amd_vangogh, snd_sof_amd_acp63
03:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller [103c:8a0e]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

Also I checked rfkill list:
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

I tried the workaround for the iwlwifi, but I had to rename the zst file instead. However it had no effect after the restart.
# mv /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm  /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.bak
mv: cannot stat '/usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm': No such file or directory

# mv /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm.zst  /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm.zst.bak

Other diagnostic information seems useless, as they are not returning any results...

dmesg | grep iwl
modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl
sudo lshw -C network

Later edit with further debug information as per @waltinator
wireless-info script output with removed information regarding Connection information because the passwords were not masked, and has no effect on the current issue. Unfortunately posting this information doesn't answer my question as to why the WiFi card is not being detected

########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 14 Aug 2024 21:21 EEST +0300

Booted last: 14 Aug 2024 00:00 EEST +0300

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

##### kernel ############################

Linux 6.8.0-40-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jul  5 10:34:03 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /root/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 30c9:0065 Luxvisions Innotech Limited HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

cfg80211             1323008  0
hp_wmi                 28672  0
sparse_keymap          12288  1 hp_wmi
platform_profile       12288  1 hp_wmi
wmi_bmof               12288  0
wmi                    28672  3 hp_wmi,video,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search lan

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root        1214       1  0 21:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

<Connection information removed because the passwords were not masked>

[/lib/netplan/00-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Bucharest (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (755 - 928 @ 2), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko.zst
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       6.8.0-40-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   88.766012] r8152 2-1.2:1.0: load rtl8153b-2 v2 04/27/23 successfully
[   88.794000] r8152 2-1.2:1.0 eth0: v1.12.13

########## wireless info END ############

and regarding sudo journalctl -b 0 I don't know what to look for, and it's rather big...
Here is some extract

sudo journalctl -b 0 | grep 00:02.2 (The Id that shows up when the card is connected)

Aug 14 21:16:58 MobileBattleStation kernel: pci 0000:00:02.2: [1022:1634] type 01 class 0x060400 PCIe Root Port
Aug 14 21:16:58 MobileBattleStation kernel: pci 0000:00:02.2: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
Aug 14 21:16:58 MobileBattleStation kernel: pci 0000:00:02.2:   bridge window [mem 0xfcf00000-0xfcffffff]
Aug 14 21:16:58 MobileBattleStation kernel: pci 0000:00:02.2: enabling Extended Tags
Aug 14 21:16:58 MobileBattleStation kernel: pci 0000:00:02.2: broken device, retraining non-functional downstream link at 2.5GT/s
Aug 14 21:16:58 MobileBattleStation kernel: pci 0000:00:02.2: retraining failed
Aug 14 21:16:58 MobileBattleStation kernel: pci 0000:00:02.2: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
Aug 14 21:16:58 MobileBattleStation kernel: pci 0000:00:02.2: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
Aug 14 21:16:58 MobileBattleStation kernel: pci 0000:00:02.2: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
Aug 14 21:16:58 MobileBattleStation kernel: pci 0000:00:02.2:   bridge window [mem 0xfcf00000-0xfcffffff]
Aug 14 21:16:58 MobileBattleStation kernel: pci 0000:00:02.2: Adding to iommu group 2
Aug 14 21:16:58 MobileBattleStation kernel: pcieport 0000:00:02.2: PME: Signaling with IRQ 35



journalctl -b 0 | grep 8087

Aug 14 21:16:58 MobileBattleStation kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0032, bcdDevice= 0.00
Aug 14 21:17:02 MobileBattleStation sbkeysync[1198]:     99d7ada0d67e5233108dbd76702f4b168087cfc4ec65494d6ca8aba858febada
Aug 14 21:17:02 MobileBattleStation sbkeysync[1198]:     99d7ada0d67e5233108dbd76702f4b168087cfc4ec65494d6ca8aba858febada


journalctl -b 0 | grep ax210 is empty


Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command sudo journalctl  -b 0.

This question is similar to: My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Prior to some attempt to understand the problem ("WiFi doesn't work, Ubuntu doesn't see it"), posting reams of "infor?ation", that may (or may not) relate to the information needed to address your problem, is of little use. Just sayin'

Hello @waltinator
OK, so after my initial post, I added the information that you mentioned in your comments.
Now what other information would be needed to help diagnose the issue so that I can:

Get my card to work.
Help other people solve this issue if they encounter it as well.

